# Extracting nested Double[] array from Tuple2

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark, tuples

I have created a List with Nested tuples (for computational reasons), and I am unable to properly extract the contents of it. (java newbie as well)

`List<Tuple2<Tuple2<Double, Integer>, Tuple2<Double, Integer>>> r = cartesian.collect(); System.out.println(r.get(0)._1._1);`

gives [0.3516409608778351, 0.3516409608778351, 0.3516409608778351, -0.33691648632337207, -0.7180063963101246]

My question is how to store this to a Double[] array
So far I've tried a few things, all give me the same error:
`class com.google.common.primitives.Doubles$DoubleArrayAsList cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double`

Comment: Please show us the code you are trying to use to store a double. From your error message, it sounds like you are trying to do something like `Double value = someCodeThatReturnsAList;` which won't work, instead you need to save the results to a list `List<Double> values = someCodeThatReturnsAList;`

Comment: `List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(r.get(0)._1._1));`
Tried things like these, they all give the same error,
even `System.out.println(r.get(0)._1._1.getClass());`
gives the same error

Comment: I think it is because `Tuple2` are immutable, I should encapsule my data in an class, and run from there, I will update with a solution